# How to Create Alternating Sub List from List in C?

Tags: c, linked-list, sequence

Suppose I have a linked list with the following structure:

```
typedef struct _Node {
   int value;
   struct _Node *next;
} Node;

3 -> 0 -> 4 -> 5 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 11 -> NULL
```

My goal is to turn this into a big list composed of different sub-lists in alternating order.

This is the structure that is essentially the "list of lists":

```
typedef struct _List {
   Node *node;
   struct _List *next;
} List;
```

My end goal would be to create a something that looks like this:

```
// [] denotes a sub list not an array
[3 -> 5 -> 1 - > NULL] -> [0 -> 3 -> 11 -> NULL] -> [4 -> 2 -> NULL]
```

I have already created the list that contains the nodes and a List structure that is composed of 2 other lists. I have already tried implementing a sequence that is able to produce this, however, I am struggling when after finding the nTh node to put in the new sub list, how can I change its next to point the correct new nTh node.

For example: Suppose I have a smaller linked list : `1 -> 5 -> 8 -> 10 -> NULL`

When I add the `1` to my first sub-list it will still be pointing to 5 which still points to 8, and so on. My actual goal would be for 1 to now point to 8 and 8 point to NULL, then in the second sub list 5 would point to 10 and 10 points to NULL.

The following code I have has the correct sequence that I want and prints it in such, yet, I have been able to create the proper code for the linked list creation. Is there any method or function that would be helpful in order to achieve this solution?

```
  Node * list; // suppose that the head has a value of 3 which points to 0 and so on
  List * bigList; // suppose that bigList points to 2 other lists in 
  bigList -> node = list; // first node in first list points to the node list (3)

  k = 3; // sub-lists that are created
  size = 8; // number of nodes in the linked list
  
  for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
    for(int j = i; j < size; j += k){
    // here is where I would have to manipulate list and weave it into different sub lists
      fprintf(stdout, "%d -> ", getNode(list, j) -> value); // prints correct sequence (getNode is a function that finds the nTh node in the list)
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
  }
```

Comment: Style guide: in C code, the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly
because they are [postfix operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3).
They should not be written with spaces around them.
Writing `bigList -> node` is not idiomatic C and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use `bigList->node`.

Comment: Are you leaving the original list unmodified, or can you dismantle it as you go?  The technique is fairly similar – it is just a question of whether you create new nodes as you split, or whether you retarget the existing nodes.  Either way, it is probably best to step through the original list, collecting the pointer to the next node, then adding the current node to the relevant new list (which might be one element of an array of lists that you use in cyclic order).  You should also create a function that prints a given list, which you can call once for each of the new lists.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've writing `foo -> bar` for 9 years now... it's a lot more readable to me. Style is ultimately very personal; the best choice of style is ultimately what you can read better. The fact that the operator is near the top of the precedence list doesn't matter as much as the fact that `foo->bar` can be mistaken for `foo>bar` when reading quickly to me.

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789— please don't send me code to review. Don't try to contribute code formatted like that to almost any open source C (or C++) project.  It is likely to be rejected by those in charge.  Who writes `foo>bar` when they mean `foo > bar` anyway?  Spacing is important — and the absence of spacing in the correct places is important too.  See K&R — though I use Allman brace positioning instead of 1TBS (for my work — I conform to the project guidelines when necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of always inserting into the first list, you should insert into the *current* list, and update that to point to the next list after every insertion. This is fairly easy to achieve with an extra pointer:

```c
void insert_node_into_list (Node ** list, int value) {
  Node * node = malloc(sizeof *node);
  *node = (Node) {.value = value, .next = NULL};
  while (*list) list = &(**list).next;
  *list = node;
}

void new_list (List ** superlist) {
  // since we're creating all superlists at once, they can be inserted in any order
  // so we do it at the front, since it's faster
  List * list = malloc(sizeof *list);
  *list = (List) {.node = NULL, .next = *superlist};
  *superlist = list;
}

void insert_node_into_superlist (List * superlist, List ** current, int value) {
  insert_node_into_list(&(**current).node, value);
  *current = (**current).next;
  if (!*current) *current = superlist;
}
```

And now you only have to construct your lists like so:

```c
List * superlist = NULL;
unsigned x;
for (x = 0; x < 3; x ++) new_list(&superlist);
List * current = superlist;
insert_node_into_superlist(superlist, &current, 3);
insert_node_into_superlist(superlist, &current, 0);
insert_node_into_superlist(superlist, &current, 4);
insert_node_into_superlist(superlist, &current, 5);
insert_node_into_superlist(superlist, &current, 3);
insert_node_into_superlist(superlist, &current, 2);
insert_node_into_superlist(superlist, &current, 1);
insert_node_into_superlist(superlist, &current, 11);
```

The `current` pointer will always point to the next sublist to use for insertion, and thus it will walk through all the sublists in the superlist. Since it's reset to the start of the superlist when it reaches the end (by the `if (!*current) *current = superlist;` line), this ensures that the values are inserted into each sublist in a rotating fashion.

Comment: This is very helful. I didn't think to use a super list which is actually very efficient considering the issue that I was having.